# Python equivalent of @ElementCollection @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)

Tags: python, java, oop, translate, verify

I am unable to understand what @ElementCollection does in this code. I need to write its Python equivalent.

```
package project.models;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity

public class Movie extends BaseModel {
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Actor> actors;

    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private List<Feature> movieFeatures;

    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private List<Genre> genre;
}
```

I have to write this class. Can someone verify if this is correct?

```
class Movie(BaseModel):
   def __init__(self, name, actors, movieFeatures, genre):
       self.name = name
       self.actors = actors
       self.movieFeatures = movieFeatures
       self.genre = genre
```

Comment: Where that annotation comes from? What's its package?

Comment: I have added the imports and other annotations in this file.

Comment: I'm guessing it comes from javax.persistence but we should not need to guess.

Comment: @aled, it's part of _Java EE_.  _[ElementCollection (Java(TM) EE 7 Specification APIs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html)_.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am unable to understand what @ElementCollection does in this code. I need to write its Python equivalent. ..."*

That is an *Annotation*, here is the *Java* tutorial.
*[Lesson: Annotations (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)*.

More specifically, it appears this code is mapping the fields to a database.

> *"... I have to write this class. Can someone verify if this is correct? ..."*

So far it looks correct.

Please post the code for *BaseModel*, *Actor*, *Feature*, and *Genre*, as the *annotations* in these classes will help determine the correct *Python* code.

Comment: @aled, you are unsure if this is a comment or an answer?

Comment: correct. An answer should not include a request for additional details.